# UIRotationGestureRecognizer to rtate the image

Tags: ios

UIRotationGestureRecognizer using in iOS to rotate an image. After rotate to save the image in same angle

how to save the image in same angle

```
[image1 drawInRect:CGRectMake(xx1,yy1, img1Width-5, img1Height-50)];
// Apply supplied opacity if applicable
[image2 drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:0.8];

UIImage *resultingImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return resultingImage;
```

Comment: What do you mean by save the image in same angle? Have you stripped out any important code here?

Comment: Where is your image rotation code